# Google Spreadsheet ImportXML to RSS all in one field

Tags: rss, google-sheets, yahoo-pipes

I have [this Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkcbsMNVZJkDdEI4b3BNb0luV3NoeWFWVFlVbGFmZlE) and I want to break down the table elements from [this page](http://www.ephotozine.com/exhibitions) to create a tidy RSS. I'm using this importXML to populate the fields in the columns:

=importXml("http://www.ephotozine.com/exhibitions"; "//div[@class='box']//table")

However whilst it populates the cells in the columns sort of correctly when I export it as RSS and run it through yahoo pipes it ends up bunching together all the fields into incomprehensible rubbish [see here](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=6063ea020ba06b952b10601a9a4601a3).

What should I be using to break out each table row with the corerctly titled field to make my tidy RSS?

Answer (score 0):

As "google spreadsheet" can also export as CSV, you could :

**A)** In "google spreadsheet" get the export as csv URL

**B)** In "yahoo pipes"

1. Use the "fetch csv" module to get the different fields from the csv URL.
2. Build your rss item from these fields.